# Apache Spark Mllib Word2Vec Model Giving Nan in Cosine Similarity

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I have a very large dataset of `Seq[String]` type.
I am trying to create `Word2VecModel` of `mllib` type.

when I feed corpus with 5 Million sentences to `Word2VecModel` its working fine but when I increase the input corpus to 7.5 Million sentences then it corrupt.

Corrupt in the sense when I use `findSynonyms` method its start giving strange synonyms with cosine similarity `NaN`.

but the word2vec model with 5 million sentences gives correct output.

Here is the Code :-

```
val cleanedRDD = sqlContext.read.parquet(HDFS_URL + corpusPath).rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Seq[String]](0))
val word2Vec = new Word2Vec().setNumPartitions(100).setMinCount(3).setNumIterations(iteration).setVectorSize(200)
val word2VecModel = word2Vec.fit(cleanedRDD)
```

I tried creating with vector size 100 and 200 
any suggestion will be appriated.